# Number of ways of scheduling applicants for an interview

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My question is this: A company has 15 applicants to interview, and 3 are to be invited on each day of the working week. In how many ways can the applicants be scheduled?

->SO this the formula being used; whn a total of n balls are to be put into k boxes with the conditions that there will be n1 balls in box 1, n2 balls inbox 2, and so on, with nk balls being placed in box k (n1 +···+nk =n) the number of doing this is: **n!/{n1!×···×nk!}**, with which I obtain 168168000 which is correct but my question is;

-> why aren't we accounting for the fact that the interview can be on any day of the week? like the days of the week listed are: s_ m_ t_ w_ t_ f_ s_  so if I put 3 candidates each in S,M,T,W,T I satisfy the conditions of the formula, but then why not account for the remaining 2 days? Shouldn't I multiply by 3! by considering S,M,T,W,T as a single unit and T,F separate to get the schedules in ANY day of the week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of the problem, the other two days don't exist. It said **working** week.

Comment: okay, so thats why. but would my method work given that the question didn't mention working days?

Comment: @FarhanNoor As long as it said $5$ days, it would work. Those five days could be Tuesday to Saturday, for instance.

Comment: i see. thanks for this insight. I was having quite the difficulty with this one, going over note, resources and equations; i think i can work well in these cases now onwards.